# MapInfo Pro 12.5 halo font in layout window

Tags: mapinfo, layouts, font

I wonder if it is possible to add halo font in Layout window in MapInfo Pro 12.5.

I was trying to do this but this option is disable.
Is any way to do this in MapInfo Pro or how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two answers to this question: yes and no.

In the 32 bit version of MapInfo Pro 12.5 you can use the Halo font effect on your text.

I'm however assuming that you are using the new Layout Designer window from either MapInfo Pro 12.5 32 bit or 64 bit. In this new layout window type, this font effect isn't supported.

I would recommend that you have a look at [our Ideas Portal](http://ideas.pb.com/) to see if this request has already been put there and if not add it yourself.

MapInfo Pro 16.0 has added support for the missing font styles, including Halo.